# If $\int\limits_\gamma f(z)dz\in\Bbb R$ does it imply $f(z)\in \Bbb R~\forall z\in\gamma$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

If $\int\limits_\gamma f(z)dz\in\Bbb R$ does it imply $f(z)\in \Bbb R~\forall z\in\gamma$?

This is from a proof where $\gamma$ is a circle and we have $1={1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_\gamma f(z)dz={1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_\gamma Re~f(z)dz$ and I'm unsure how the second equality is justified.

Clearily $0=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}ie^{it}dt$ and $ie^{it}\notin \Bbb R$...

Comment: The answer is no. For example, if $\gamma$ is a closed path and $f(z)$ is holomorphic, then the integral is $0$, and $0 \in \Bbb R$. This does not mean that $f$ is real on $\gamma$.

Comment: Further specialized example.  $f(z) = i$ the constant, and $\gamma$ is the unit circle.  Then $\int_\gamma f(z)\;dz = 0$ but $f(z)$ is never real.

Comment: Also $\int_\gamma f(z) dz \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ does **not** imply that there is a $z$ with $f(z) \in \mathbb{C}$. Take $f \equiv 1$ and $\gamma: [0, pi] \to \mathbb{C}$ with $\gamma(t) := e^{it}$. (Naively one could see curve integration as just summation of the function values over the curve, but this severely fails!)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac1{2\pi} \int_\gamma f(z) \ \mathrm dz = 1$$

Comparing real parts:
$$\Re \left( \frac1{2\pi} \int_\gamma f(z) \ \mathrm dz \right) = 1$$

Taking real parts commutes with everything:
$$1 = \Re \left( \frac1{2\pi} \int_\gamma f(z) \ \mathrm dz \right) = \frac1{2\pi} \Re \left( \int_\gamma f(z) \ \mathrm dz \right) = \frac1{2\pi} \int_\gamma \Re \left( f(z) \right) \ \mathrm dz$$

---

Notice, though, that $\displaystyle \int_\gamma \Re \left( f(z) \right) \ \mathrm dz = \int_\gamma f(z) \ \mathrm dz$ does not imply $\Re \left( f(z) \right) = f(z)$.

Comment: That's not justification, that's just saying it works because it works

Comment: @Jakobian but that's pointing out the author's mistake in thinking that we somehow deduced $f(z) \in \Bbb R$ when writing down that equality.

Answer (score 0):

A you talking about a curve Integral?

If yes then f is probably a One-Form: 
Integration over a curve  $\gamma : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as follows:

$$
\int_\gamma f(z) dz=\int_a^b f(\gamma(z))\gamma'(z) dz
$$

(I know this should be a comment rather than an answer but i don't have sufficient points jet)